# Converting checksummed address to non-checksummed address

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, checksum

I'm aware that the web3 library has the `toCheckSumAddress` method that converts an upper or lowercase Ethereum address to a checksum address. Am wondering if there is any method available that converts a checksummed address to a non-checksummed address (all lowercase)?

The reason I'm doing this is because a subgraph that I'm sending requests to only takes non-checksummed addresses. Thank you!

Comment: .toLowerCase() should work

Comment: As @MajdTL said, you just need to convert the string to all LowerCase. And that is it.

Answer (score 0):

For javascript:

```
var checkSum = "0xcAd7311601AD5D7CfaCceB3A5A010957A4332F4b"
console.log(checkSum.toLowerCase())
```

A [JSfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/b92a3L6d/1/)